# playing a video on the page in silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I looked around on google and I'm not so sure what would be the best (in my case, fastest to build) way to have a video file that's on the server (what format should I store it in? wmv?) play on an aspx web page using .net 4.

I'd like to use silverlight with this snippet that I found online:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MyVid"
              Source="http://abc.xyz.com/MyVid.wmv"
              Height="250"
              Width="350"
              AutoPlay="False"/>
```

If you have experienced this situation and have suggestions that'd be great.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, that should be possible. Would it be better? If so, how would it work?

Comment: using html5, you gain the [video tag](http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html) that allows you to simply tell where are your video, with multiple formats to match target browsers. SilverLight, like Flash, are still options, but require proprietary plugins. The last words will come from your target browser requirement (I live SilverLigth for enterprise apps, but for internet sites, Html 5 is the logical choice)

Comment: Can you show some sample code to make this work?

Comment: I don't know if "frenchie" means you are french, but if you read french, there a very pedagogic lab on the [french msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ie/hh237531)

Comment: yes, I'm French, but the site is not so good. I'll do some research on HTML5 video instead of using Silverlight. Thanks.

Comment: The page I provided has "Cahiers de vacances" with a specific document for embedding videos on html pages. This is actually what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the tip on HTML5 alternative; post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target requirements allow it, you should use Html 5 video tag. There are [some good articles explaining how to use it](http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1125-introduction-balise-video-html5-mp4-h264-webm-ogg-theora.html).

To synthetise, you can use the video like this :

```
<video width="400" height="222" controls="controls">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  message if the browser is not html5 compliant here
</video>
```

You can specify several source, in order to support a larger number of browser (unfortunately, even if the video tag is standard, the CODEC are not).

Another good article is available in the [Msdn France - "cahiers de vacances"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ie/hh237531). The 1st volume is explaining the approach, and also the alternative for non-html5 browser, which consists in putting either a flash or SilverLigth player in place of the video tag.